# how to compile scss styles inside a blade file

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use scss styles inside a blade file. but I can't find a propper way to do that.

```
{{-- header.blade.php --}}
<header id="mainHeader">
    <style lang="scss">
        .a1 {
            color: red;

            > .a2 {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <div class="a1">
        this is a1

        <div class="a2">this is a2</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is your reason to do this? Maybe there is a better solution than separating this section from your main SCSS folder(s). If you don't use any variables or functions this could easily be plain css without a compiler.

Comment: I prefer scss styling syntax. separating is my current solution and I already know how to do that. but it is not great solution. I'm trying to put styles inside or near the blade files. ... thanks anyway.
@ArnoTenkink

Answer (score 1):

there is no support for this, you can't compile SCSS from `blade` templates. Unless you write/use some sort of Plugin for `laravel-mix`.

In real is just the wrong way to go about it.

I would suggest using normal `css` in blade.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it doesn't seem to be possible within blade.
Vue uses the same setup, where self contained ui components hold html, js and css. Which makes for a very modular system if you plan it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking to do something similar to this and just wanted to give anyone in the future a point in the direction I took.

My use case was a little different, we run a bunch of different websites through a tenancy platform and wanted to utilise SCSS to make customisation of the templates easier.

We essentially use blade to create the `scss` plaintext, and then to compile we use a library called SCSSPHP (https://github.com/scssphp/scssphp/).

When somebody updates their settings on our system, we re-compile their scss for them.